# Other databases with set data type like Redis

Tags: nosql, redis

The set datatype and associated operations (union, intersection, cardinality, etc.) in Redis are very useful. I have been unable to find any other databases with a comparable feature. Is anyone aware of any?

Answer (score 0):

One database that's similar to Redis is [Kyoto Tycoon](http://fallabs.com/kyototycoon/spex.html). It doesn't have sets, lists, etc., but it does have multiple database types, cursors, and a Lua extension that is similar to Redis' Lua scripting.

You could implement some Redis datatypes and commands in Lua running inside Kyoto Tycoon, but it's really just a key/value store.

Another one to look at is [Edis](https://github.com/inaka/edis): Redis implemented in Erlang.